# How to check the node exists in xml and returns the string values by reading CDATA values

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, xmldocument

I have got below xml in my string and I am using c# 2.0

```
string strXML ="<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tcm:Error xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" ErrorCode="80040329" Category="17" Source="Kernel" Severity="2">
  <tcm:Line ErrorCode="80040329" Cause="false" MessageID="16137">
    <![CDATA[Unable to save Keyword (tcm:0-0-0).]]><tcm:Token>RESID_4574</tcm:Token><tcm:Token>RESID_15309</tcm:Token><tcm:Token>tcm:0-0-0</tcm:Token>
  </tcm:Line>
  <tcm:Line ErrorCode="80040329" Cause="true" MessageID="15200">
    <![CDATA[Name must be unique for items of type: Keyword within this Category and its BluePrint context. Source or sources  of conflict: tcm:236-215788-1024,tcm:237-215788-1024,tcm:241-215788-1024,tcm:243-215788-1024,tcm:423-215788-1024.]]><tcm:Token>RESID_15214</tcm:Token><tcm:Token>RESID_15309</tcm:Token><tcm:Token>RESID_15293</tcm:Token><tcm:Token>tcm:236-215788-1024,tcm:237-215788-1024,tcm:241-215788-1024,tcm:243-215788-1024,tcm:423-215788-1024</tcm:Token>
  </tcm:Line>
  <tcm:Details>
    <tcm:CallStack>
      <tcm:Location>UtilitiesBL.AssertUniqueTitle</tcm:Location>
      <tcm:Location>UtilitiesBL.AssertUniqueTitle</tcm:Location>
      <tcm:Location>KeywordBL.Create</tcm:Location>
      <tcm:Location>XMLState.Save</tcm:Location>
      <tcm:Location>Keyword.Save</tcm:Location>
    </tcm:CallStack>
  </tcm:Details>
</tcm:Error>"
```

Now I want to write a function which will first check whether string strXML has the xml node  node in it, if there is no such node then return "valid" else my function will return the string values taken from above xml.

So my return result will be "**Unable to save Keyword (tcm:0-0-0). Name must be unique for items of type: Keyword within this Category and its BluePrint context. Source or sources  of conflict: tcm:236-215788-1024,tcm:237-215788-1024,tcm:241-215788-1024,tcm:243-215788-1024,tcm:423-215788-1024.**", these text are there in XML.

Please suggest!!

Thanks.

MS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(strXML);

XmlNamespaceManager xmlnsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("tcm", "http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0");

XmlNodeList res = xml.SelectNodes("//tcm:Line/text()", xmlnsManager);


foreach (XmlNode item in res)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.InnerText);
}
```

Comment: ok thanks Kirill, can you also please suggest how to check that particular node exists in string before loading to XmlDocument. As my strXML can be xml string as well as normal string depends on what type of result is returns, do I need to use .contains or is there any other way around

Comment: @M.S, I suggest you to check `res.Count` property, e.g.: `if (res.Count == 0) {...}`. It is better than check string with `Contains`.

Comment: But how we can get (res.Count == 0) before uploading whole string to XmlDocument, please suggest!!

Comment: @M.S, There is no way one can.

Comment: Well I have used contains function to check whether it has tcm:error text in it or not and then I have loaded in xml document..thanks for your help